# fast motion part a video anywhere with Fmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use fast motion effect on my videos.
I found this command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex \
"[0:v]trim=0:10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; \
 [0:v]trim=10:30,setpts=(PTS-STARTPTS)*2[v2]; \
 [0:v]trim=start=30,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v3]; \
 [0:a]atrim=0:10,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1]; \
 [0:a]atrim=10:30,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,atempo=0.5[a2]; \
 [0:a]atrim=start=30,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a3]; \   
 [v1][a1][v2][a2][v3][a3]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" \
-map [v] -map [a] output.mp4
```

Let's say I have a 10 minutes long video. 
I want to apply the above command line with videos.
Can you help me?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What is wrong with the command? What did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: This command line does not apply to long videos.
It only works for 1 minute videos

Comment: Yeah, that is obvious, so you have to change the times in the filter. We don't know which times you want. You have to define that yourself.